# How can we pass variable in oscmd command in sas

Tags: sas, sas-stored-process

I am using oscmd command to run some operating system operation from sas, but want to make it generic by passing the varible in oscmd command.
I am using below code:
`%global name =skstar; filename oscmd pipe "python test.py --inputvar=&name.";`
The value of variable'name'is not replace in command.

EDIT: the above part is working now , its just a quotation mistake. but wanted to know the way to abort the oscmd cli command ,if in case parameter value passed is wrong

Comment: Are you sure `name` has been assigned correctly? Try `%put &=name` in you editor to check it.

Comment: What value did you assign to the macro variable `NAME`?   How are you using the fileref `OSCMD`?

Comment: @whymath , I have checked that ,by using put statement value is assignned correctly . and also checked the put statement for whole oscmd , but &name. variable value is not raplaced in command. @Tom, i have assigned ```%global name =skstar```;

Comment: that is not correct syntax.  Please share the results from your log, including the variable assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe your datastep is wrong but you not write there. It's work fine:

```
%let name=test words;
filename oscmd pipe "echo &name.";

data _null_;
 infile oscmd;
 input;
 put _infile_;
run;

/*log:
NOTE: The infile OSCMD is:
      Unnamed Pipe Access Device,
      PROCESS=echo test words,RECFM=V,LRECL=32767

test words
NOTE: 1 record was read from the infile OSCMD.
      The minimum record length was 10.
      The maximum record length was 10.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.18 seconds
      cpu time            0.03 seconds


*/
```

Comment: Thanks @imnorobot, it worked . but wanted to know how can we abort the perticular command triggered in oscmd ,if incase some wrong parameter value passed to oscmd command. which options are available in SAS for that

Comment: I think this is an OS call so you cannot abort from sas. The called program need handle the bad parameters and other mistake. You can read the called program system outputs  and you can work with the answers in the sas step if you want.